# Let wrap take full width

Tags: flutter

How can I make the red box to use full width and put the button to the very right of the screen when wrapping?

[image: Should take full width]

Also I want `spaceBetween` if the button is not wrapping, but it does not work:

[image: Should take full width and spaceBetween]

This is what I have sofar:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Please wrap on small screens",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Bearbeiten"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    // ...
  ]
)
```

Comment: Wrap the `Container` with `Row` widget and `Expanded` as Row's child.

Comment: That will align the text and button both right (or left) but I need the text left and the button right (like spacebetween)

Comment: the first image is what you want right? second is what you have upto now?

Comment: @Blasanka no both images represent my current situation (but different wrapping behavior depending on the length of text VS screen size). Both are negative examples. I want the button at the right side of the screen (expanding the red area to full width).

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

Finally, I manage to solve your problem. Probably is not a canonic way, but it's working.

You need to compute the total width of your content in order to compare it with the width of the screen (the width is the width of the widgets, plus space you want between widgets, plus padding from both sides).

With that, you are able to know when you need to change the layout, and you can apply the layout you want to each case.

Here I leave the code:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey textKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey buttonKey = GlobalKey();

  double widthLimit = double.infinity;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      final textBox = textKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      final buttonBox = buttonKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

      widthLimit = textBox.size.width + buttonBox.size.width + 8 + 16 * 2;
    });
  }

  Widget _wrap(bool spaceBetween, Widget child) => spaceBetween
      ? child
      : Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: child,
        );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Builder(builder: (context) {
            final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
            final spaceBetween = screenWidth >= widthLimit;

            return Wrap(
              crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
              alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("Please wrap on small screen small screen", key: textKey),
                _wrap(
                    spaceBetween,
                    TextButton(
                      key: buttonKey,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text("Bearbeiten"),
                    )),
              ],
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Old Answer

I am going to take a couple of premises from your screenshots:

1. The `Wrap` doesn't have to take the full width by default
2. You only want to go to two lines when there is not enough space in the device screen.

With that, you can make what you want with this code:

```dart
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Wrap(
      spacing: 8,
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
      alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Text("Please wrap on small screen"),
        TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Bearbeiten")),
      ]),
),
```

I added the `spacing` property to the `Wrap` to provide space as you wanted when both widgets are at the same line. Also, I set the alignment of the `Wrap` to `end` to align as you want.

When there is not enough space on the screen, the widget is going to move to a new line and align to the end. As the first widget is longer than the wrapped one and, as I said in the premises, we don't need to take the full width of the screen, `Wrap` will adapt to keep things aligned properly.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not put the button to the right side of the screen (neither when wrapping nor when on a single line). It only aligns the button to the right end of the text.

Comment: I get your point. I updated my answer with another solution!

Comment: I appreciate your work on finding a solution. I think it is too complicated for the effect it should provide and makes the code too hard to understand for other devs. Thanks anyway - I give you an upvote, but I leave to question open for potential other answers. For now we stick with a left aligned button if it wraps and use @Blasanka version from the comment.